# How to stop loading the page after clicking on an href link in html?

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-forms

so this code
`<a href="" onclick="alert('ITEM ADDED TO WATCHLIST')">Add to your watchlist</a>` When i click on the link, an alert pops up from the upper side and when i clicks the OK button, it reloads the page .I want it, not to reload the page after clicking and just stays right where the page currently is.

Comment: You should be using a `<button>` element instead on an anchor tag. An anchor tag is supposed to represent navigation, while a button is preferable for use cases like yours.

Comment: yeah i've added that in my code..thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `javascript:void(0)` in your href attribute, this will prevent default action of element.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert('ITEM ADDED TO WATCHLIST')">Add to your watchlist</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

it reloads because you use selector `<a href="">`. You might want to use other construction, for example, `<span onclick="alert('ITEM ADDED TO WATCHLIST')">Add to your watchlist</span>`, then no page reload.